# How do include javascript file on nodejs, not the require module format

Tags: javascript, node.js

Could the file not formatted with the require module is include in other file on nodejs?

I need to use the javascript file for browsers on nodejs. The file is not formatted with the required module. (That's mean that do not use module.exports=)
How the file is included or loaded in other javascript file?

I try to use node-import(https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-import),
but the module will crash when passing the absolute path.

I do not want to modify the browser javascritp file.

Thank for taking your time.

Comment: How do you define which functions and variables should be exported in those files?

Comment: @t.niese The file contains only "(function ($){ ~;$.myfunc=myfunc})(jQuery)". This is some of a jQuery plugin. I want to run this script and the myfunc insert into jQuery. Thank for you help.

Comment: You can't use jQuery within Node.js because the main purpose of jQuery is work with the DOM. Why do you need a jQuery module server side?

Comment: @t.niese Ah...  I will make my rendering engine for express with jQuery. For the purpose, I installed jsdom and jQuery module with npm to use jQuery on the server side, and use node-import module to include the JavaScript file for browsers. Then, I succeeded to render HTML with jQuery. But, when I will make npm module,  node-import module dose not work with absolute path to the JavaScript file. So, I am looking for another include way. Thanks!

Comment: `require` does not necessary need a module,  you can also include a single file, and even for modules it works find with absolute paths (but you shouldn't do that). I never really used jsdom, but if I recall correctly all scripts you want to use in jsdom (like jquery)  have to be included using the `scripts` or `src`  property of `jsdom.env`. You should  a minimal example how you use jQuery in combination with jsdom, and how you want to load the plugin.

Comment: @t.niese  I understood what you explained. And now, I get a simple idea from your comment about using require.
I already have tried to use require and error caused for reference to jQuery variable. So I dropped using require.
But, I noticed about setting jQuery to global Object (global.jQuery = jQuery). This works well! 
Thank for your helping! . I am pleasure to talk about this problem with you!